# PHP - Help in FOR LOOP

Tags: php, arrays, function, postgresql, output

I have an array and looping through it and pushing the data using for loop.

```
$test_data = [10,20,35,01,50,60,87,12,45,86,9,85];
```

Actually that's a sample data. But my data is a result similar to that which I get from PostgreSQL, a single column data.

Using the below function for `$test_data`.

```
for( $x=0; $x < 12; $x++ ) {
    $chart_data['data1'] = $test_data[$x];
}
```

**Result :** `{"data1":{"data": 85"}}`

Here's the for loop which I use along the PostgreSQL result in the PHP.

```
for( $x=0; $x < pg_num_rows($query); $x++ ) {
    $data['data1'] = pg_fetch_assoc($query);
}
```

Even here I get only the last row in the browser when I do - `echo json_encode($data);`

Something similar to the **result** what I've mentioned above.

First 9 rows are not getting inserted into the `data[]`. Only the last row is getting added to the array.

Please say me where I'm doing the mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you want to iterate on a simple array (as `$fetch_data`) use `foreach()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since arrays cannot have same key as index.

You need to rewrite it as ..

```
for( $x=0; $x < 12; $x++ ) {
    $chart_data['data1'][] = $test_data[$x];
    //                  ^^ <--- Add that.
}
```

As *[Loic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3322400/loic)* suggested go with a `foreach` , I answered quickly so it didn't strike on my mind in the first place

```
foreach($test_data as $val)
{
 $chart_data['data1'][] = $val;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) More 12 minutes to accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could do like this (without using `pg_num_rows`):

```
// better initialize the result array
$data = array('data1' => array());

while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  // here is the point, add element to the array
  $data['data1'][] = $row;
}
```